# rewrite query string via htaccess

Tags: url-rewrite, htaccess

I want to rewrite some dynamic urls like:

https://www.test.com/my-custom-url.html/?o=price&dir=asc&new=1

to

https://www.test.com/my-custom-url.html/o/price/dir/asc/new/1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite a query string like this:

Example for one arbitrary parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-custom-url.html.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /my-custom-url.html/%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Example for 3 arbitrary parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-custom-url.html.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /my-custom-url.html/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: It replaced the URL well but now I am not able to get these parameter values via $_GET or $_REQUEST

Comment: OK, that was not part of your question :-) For that you need an additional line, for example this for one parameter: `RewriteRule ^/my-custom-url.html/[a-z]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$ my-custom-url.html?$1=$2 [L]` Important: this should **not** redirect! Put it above the other rule
I'm not sure about this, it might end in an infinite loop